# Simultaneous clicks in android with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, button, firebase-realtime-database

I am totally confused on how to handle the clicks done at the same time by say, two users. The button which they are clicking is fetching the value from db incrementing it and then sending it back to firebase db. 
Now issue is when two users simultaneously click the same button the value is changing only once, i.e, if value is 0 then its changed to 1. 
What I want is one of the user should wait for some time until first one increments the value, once the value is updated then second user should be able to do the same, which finally results a value of 2 in db. 
But how to do this...?

Where and how to use a valueEvenListener(); or there is something else..?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `transaction`, the name can be confusing because every operation with the database is a transaction. But this method has some very interesting features:

- Is like a bridge with the database, it will allow you to ask for data and based on that, do something. It stays connected during that operation.
- The listener has a special method for logic and then another for UI

This is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

```
databaseRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            //Don't call the ui here, it will break the execution
            //There is no warning about this, neither a crash, but won't work

            //If you are working with a model
            YourObject object = mutableData.getValue(YourObject.class);
            int increase = object.getCounter();
            increase++;
            object.setCounter(increase);
            mutableData.setValue(object);


            //If you are not working with a model
            int counter = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class)
            counter++;
            mutableData.setValue(counter);

            //Finally you always have to return telling what happened
            //You could have other conditions here, and return the object untouched
            //If by any condition nothing happens return the original mutable data
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Here you can access the UI

            //Model case
            YourObject result = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourObject.class);
            someView.setText(String.valueOf(result.getCount()));

            //Datatype case
            int count = dataSnapshot.getValue(Interger.class);
            someView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
    });
```

A `transaction` is meant to be used in situations like this, concurrency or race conditions, are solved by querying the data right before writing it.

This is concurrency, more than one event simultaneously.
For a race imagine something like reservations, the object has `n` reservations, what if 2 users click at the same time. The one with the fastest internet gets the reservation, the other a bad luck error.

Comment: Can I write the value which I want to increment directly inside the doTransaction() method...?                                                                                  For example, num = num + 1;        and then mutableData.setValue(num);

Comment: I tried the direct updating as you have done in doTransaction() method and in onComplete() method I included a toast saying "Error", now problem is the onComplete() method is executing but doTransaction is not i.e, always am getting ERROR toast. My databaseRefe is also correctly pointing the targeted node.

Comment: @Kaushal then you will have to add your code and a database structure, please check your database rules allow it first